# Query on returned results

Tags: python, sql, pyqt

I have a model, which inherits from a QSqlTableModel, that I fill with a table from a database. Sometimes, I need to effectuate a research on the data:

```
self.query.prepare(requete)
self.query.exec_()

self.modele.setQuery(self.query)

self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.modele)
self.tableau.setModel(self.proxy)
```

The proxy is here to research a char on a field of the table, the query is here to effectuate a research on several joined tables.

My problem is, sometimes I need to effectuate a research ON the previous research. So, would you know how to set up the previous returned results as the new model ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, with

> I need to effectuate a research ON the previous research

you mean that you want to do nested queries: a `select` nested in a `select`. This is possible with `py-sql`: you call `select` a first time on your table. Let's say you named this `select`: `subselect`. Now, you call `select` on `subselect` to select rows from the first queried table. Here is an example [from `py-sql` doc](https://code.google.com/p/python-sql/).

```
    >>> user_group = Table('user_group')

    >>> subselect = user_group.select(user_group.user,
    ...     where=(user_group.active == True))

    >>> user = Table('user')

    >>> tuple(user.select(user.id, where=(user.id.in_(subselect))))
    ('SELECT "a"."id" FROM "user" AS "a" WHERE ("a"."id" IN (SELECT "b"."user" 
      FROM "user_group" AS "b" 
      WHERE ("b"."active" = %s)))', (True,))

    >>> tuple(subselect.select(subselect.user))
    ('SELECT "a"."user" FROM (SELECT "b"."user" 
      FROM "user_group" AS "b" 
      WHERE ("b"."active" = %s)) AS "a"', (True,))
```